# Bulk Update to Gridview Fails, HasControls Returns False

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, gridview

So I've got this Gridview with auto generated columns. The auto generated is necessary because the grid contents are based off of a pivot table, and most of the columns are not known ahead of time.

I then change most of the cells in the grid to text boxes, ala:

```
Protected Sub GridView1_RowDataBound(sender As Object, e As GridViewRowEventArgs) Handles GridView1.RowDataBound
    If e.Row.RowType = DataControlRowType.DataRow Then
        For i As Integer = 5 To e.Row.Cells.Count - 1
            Dim txtbox As New TextBox()
            txtbox.Text = e.Row.Cells(i).Text
            txtbox.Width = 75                
            e.Row.Cells(i).Controls.Add(txtbox)
        Next
    End If

End Sub
```

And this works like a champ. I then have a Save button which loops through all the cells and writes everything back to my datasource, like so:

```
Protected Sub ButtonSave_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles ButtonSave.Click

    Dim rowCounter As Integer = 0

    For Each row As GridViewRow In GridView1.Rows
        For columnCounter As Integer = 5 To 16

            Dim tempTextbox As TextBox = DirectCast(GridView1.Rows(rowCounter).Cells(columnCounter).Controls(0), TextBox)
            Dim intValue As Integer = CInt(tempTextbox.Text)

            SqlDataSourceExcelGridTest.UpdateParameters.Clear()
            SqlDataSourceExcelGridTest.UpdateParameters.Add("DepartmentNumber", GridView1.Rows(rowCounter).Cells(2).Text)
            SqlDataSourceExcelGridTest.UpdateParameters.Add("ProjectNumber", GridView1.Rows(rowCounter).Cells(3).Text)
            SqlDataSourceExcelGridTest.UpdateParameters.Add("Alias", GridView1.Rows(rowCounter).Cells(4).Text)
            SqlDataSourceExcelGridTest.UpdateParameters.Add("WorkWeek", GridView1.HeaderRow.Cells(columnCounter).Text)
            SqlDataSourceExcelGridTest.UpdateParameters.Add("WorkHours", intValue)
            SqlDataSourceExcelGridTest.Update()

        Next

        rowCounter += 1
    Next

    GridView1.DataBind()

End Sub
```

And this *almost* works. If I comment out the bits about the tempTextbox and watch my SQL Server Profiler, I see all the values are being passed correctly except for the **Workhours** - which is the editable cell. If I leave the bits about the tempTextbox, I get the error ***Specified argument was out of the range of valid values***. This happens on the declaration of tempTextbox, when DirectCasting it to the control that should be in the desired cell.

So I commented out my update logic, and instead dropped this into the Click event:

```
Response.Write("Row: " & rowCounter & " Column: " & columnCounter & " Has Controls? " & GridView1.Rows(rowCounter).Cells(columnCounter).HasControls.ToString & "<br>")
```

And every cell comes back as false. That is, no cell recognizes that it has a control in it. This appears to be why the out of range error message occurs.

Can anyone tell me why the control doesn't exist, even though I can see it plan as day on my page?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Any controls you create in RowDataBound will be lost on postback.

Comment: @Rick - That would explain it! Can you recommend where I should create the controls? RowCreated doesn't seem to do the trick.

Comment: @Rick - I got it! I just added a GridView.DataBind() on Page_Load and that did it. Thanks bud!

Comment: @Rick - Feel free to post your comment as an Answer so I can mark it as such.

Comment: Thanks.  I need dem points!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Any controls you create in RowDataBound will be lost on postback.